# Extracting file from LZMA archive with R

Tags: r, extract, tar, lzma, xz

I am trying to extract a file from a LZMA archive downloaded from an API containing JSON files, using R. On my computer I can extract the file manually in Windows Explorer with no problems.

Here's my code currently (API details removed):

```
tempFile <- tempfile()
destDir <- "extracted-files"
if (!dir.exists(destDir)) dir.create(destDir)

download.file("api_url.tar.xz", destfile = tempFile)
untar(tempFile, exdir = destDir)
```

When I attempt to extract the file, I receive the following error messages:

```
/usr/bin/tar: This does not look like a tar archive
/usr/bin/tar: Skipping to next header
/usr/bin/tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
Warning messages:
1: running command 'tar.exe -xf "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpMncPWp\file2eec75e23a15" -C "extracted-files"' had status 2 
2: In untar(tempFile, exdir = destDir) :
  ‘tar.exe -xf "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpMncPWp\file2eec75e23a15" -C "extracted-files"’ returned error code 2
```

I am using Windows 10 with R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21).

Comment: Added a solution using library(archive) which was the fastest for me, and also supports reading a file from the archive without having to unzip it first.

Answer (score 1):

Using `library(archive)` one can also read in a particular csv file within an archive without having to UNZIP it first :

```
library(archive)
library(readr)
read_csv(archive_read("api_url.tar.xz", file = 1), col_types = cols()) # adjust file=XX as appropriate
```

This is quite a bit faster.

To unzip everything one can use

`archive_extract("api_url.tar.xz", dir=XXX)`

That worked very well for me & is faster than the unbuilt untar(). It also works on all platforms. It supports 'tar', 'ZIP', '7-zip', 'RAR', 'CAB', 'gzip', 'bzip2', 'compress', 'lzma' and 'xz' formats.

Answer (score 0):

### SOLVED:

While it seemed to work perfectly on Mac, for it to work on Windows you need to open the compressed .xz file connection for reading in binary mode, before passing it to untar():

```
download.file(url, tmp)
zz <- xzfile(tmp, open = "rb")
untar(zz, exdir = destDir)
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, and even simpler solution is to specify the 'mode' parameter for download.file() as follows:

```
download.fileurl, destfile = tmp, mode = "wb")
```